# How to use Datatable js library in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, requirejs

what's the best way to use the datatable js library in my template file ? 
I tried like this but it doesn't work :

layout file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
          <css src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" src_type="url"/>
          <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" src_type="url"/>
     </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block
                template="Fmj_Portefeuill::portefeuille.phtml"
                class="Fmj\Portefeuill\Block\portefeuille"
                name="FMJ_portefeuill"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

template file :

```
<table id="portefeuilleTable"> ... </table>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        $(function(){
                $('#portefeuilleTable').DataTable();
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: this may help .. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94364/get-requirejs-config-js-to-load-declared-cdns-for-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove 
**<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" src_type="url"/>** from xml.

1. Copy **jquery.dataTables.min.js** inside **VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**. 
   So location of the file is: 
   **VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js**
2. Inside phtml template add following code

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'VendorName_ModuleName/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
    ], function($, $t){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
    })
</script>
```

Clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

you should download latest stable css and js version from "https://cdn.datatables.net" and move to "app/code/{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}//view/frontend/web/js and css folder.

add css to head section of layout xml file.

```
 <head>       
        <css src="{{vendor}}/{{modulename}}::css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>         
 </head>
```

add or change {{vendor}}/{{modulename}}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js file

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'datatable': '{{vendor}}_{{modulename}}/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
    }    
};
```

Now you can use datatables js file in phtml page.

```
<table class="custom-grid" id="datatable_example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="data-grid-th">heading1</th>
        <th class="data-grid-th">heading2</th>
        <th class="data-grid-th">heading3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td >row11</td>
        <td >row12</td>
        <td >row13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >row21</td>
        <td >row22</td>
        <td >row33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >row31</td>
        <td >row32</td>
        <td >row33</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    require(['jquery','datatable'], function($) {
        $('#datatable_example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In layout file add

`<head>
          <css src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" src_type="url"/>
          <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" src_type="url"/>
     </head>`

```
<table class="data-grid" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="data-grid-th">ID</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td >1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'VendorName_ModuleName/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
    ],
    function($, alert) {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    }
```